# How to escape a JSON object to feed into a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, xamarin

Really struggling with this one! I'm building an Android and iPhone application that shows a `WebView` (`UIWebView` on iOS). The `WebView` has an HTML page loaded in it which contains a simple JavaScript function defined as follows:

```
function parseJson(input)
{
  alert("start of parseJson(...) JavaScript method");
  var parsedJson = JSON.parse(input);
  alert("end of parseJson(...) JavaScript method");
}
```

What I want to do is to call my `parseJson(input)` JavaScript function from the Android/iOS client passing in a `string` as the input parameter. This is done as follows for Xamarin.Android:

```
string json = "{}"
myWebView.LoadUrl ("javascript:parseJson(\"" + json + "\")"));
```

And as follows for Xamarin.iOS:

```
string json = "{}"
myWebView.EvaluateJavascript ("parseJson(\"" + json + "\")");
```

Up to here, this works fine. No problem. The JavaScript function is called and executes. Also, I know I have to double-escape the quotation-mark character in my `string`, as follows:

```
string json = "{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}";
```

This also works fine. The JavaScript function is called and executes. Double escaping `"\r"` and `"\n"` (to `"\\\r"` and `"\\\n"`) also works. However, if the JSON string contains a `"\\"`, `"\b"`, `"\t"` or `"\f"`, then the `JSON.parse(...)` call in my JavaScript function falls over (even if the character is double-escaped).

Any ideas on how I can reliably escape my JSON string from within the client before I feed it into my JavaScript function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I have to escape the parameters to be fed into my JavaScript function something as follows:

```
string EscapeJavaScriptFunctionParameter(string param) {
  char[] chars = param.ToCharArray();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();

  for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
  {
    switch (chars [i]) {
    case '\\':
      sb.Append ("\\\\");
      break;
    case '\n':
      sb.Append ("\\n");
      break;
    case '\r':
      sb.Append ("\\r");
      break;
    case '\b':
      sb.Append ("\\b");
      break;
    case '\f':
      sb.Append ("\\f");
      break;
    case '\t':
      sb.Append ("\\t");
      break;
    default:
      sb.Append (chars[i]);
      break;
  }

  return sb.ToString ();
}
```

This is not a complete escape method but just demonstrates how to escape the most common JavaScript special characters.

Using this method, I call my JavaScript function from my Android project as follows:

```
string json = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
string escapedJson = EscapeJavaScriptFunctionParameter(json);
myWebView.LoadUrl ("javascript:parseJson(JSON.stringify(" + escapedJson + "))");
```

And from my iOS project as follows:

```
string json = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
string escapedJson = EscapeJavaScriptFunctionParameter(json);
myWebView.EvaluateJavascript ("parseJson(JSON.stringify(" + escapedJson + "))");
```

Comment: I found I needed to escape the apostrophe, so I added the following:  
      
    case 39: //Apostrophe  
        sb.append("\\'");  
        break;

Comment: This method doesn't escape " and '. The page can get hacked if you don't escape quotes.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully @Bogden: "... This is not a complete escape method but just demonstrates how to escape the most common JavaScript special characters..."

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try something like: (or for cases that don't work for you)

```
myWebView.EvaluateJavascript("parseJson('{\"key\":\"value\"}')");
```

JSON.stringify() looks useful too in your case:

```
myWebView.EvaluateJavascript("parseJson(JSON.stringify({key:value}))");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using single quotes (i.e. ') around the JSON object string won't work in case the string itself contains a single quote. The `JSON.stringify(...)` method on the other hand is proving to be a jewel! Thanks for that. I still haven't entirely got to the solution but I think I'm almost there. Watch this space...

Comment: Almost perfect, just needed JSON.stringify({\"key\":\"value\"})